# How to prevent button form Angular?

Tags: angular

I have a search form:

```
<form class="navbar-form">
    <div class="input-group no-border">
        <input type="text" #term class="form-control" (keyup.enter)="search()" placeholder="поиск..." />
        <button class="btn btn-white btn-round btn-just-icon" (click)="search()">
            <i class="material-icons">search</i>
            <div class="ripple-container"></div>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

It should search by `click` and `key.enter`:

```
search(): void {
   const value = this.term.nativeElement.value ? this.term.nativeElement.value.toString().trim() : null;
   this.router.navigate(['search?=' + value]);
```

Problem is when I click over button it reloads page. Also I don't like condition `const value = this.term.nativeElement.value ? this.term.nativeElement.value.toString().trim() : null;`

How can I improve it?

I have tried to pass `$event`: `search($event)`.

```
search(e) {
   e.eventPrevent();
}
```

It does not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use [preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

```
private search(event){
  event.preventDefault()
}
```

and this to prevent default submit behavior (reload)

```
<form (submit)="$event.preventDefault()">
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

in your particular example I would replace the wrapping `<form>` tag with just `<div>`. that will do the trick and everything should work

Answer (score 0):

Just use `type="button"`. For explanation see https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_pushbutton_type.asp

Answer (score 0):

Add **type="button"**

```
<button class="btn btn-white btn-round btn-just-icon" type="button (click)="search()">
```

and make **search** function return false